# Move file on django storage s3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I'm using django-storages with amazon s3, with a configuration close to this guide: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Now I have a situation where I want to rename a lot of files when the model is saved, before implemented the s3 storage backend I simply called os.rename:

```
os.rename(initial_path, new_path)
```

Since that obviously doesnt work with django-storages, is there a a way of doing that differently using the storage's capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably should have found out by now s3 has only create, copy and delete methods. So you should implement a function that would rename: copy-with-new-name & delete-old. You can then put this function by redefining save method of a model OR by implementing django signals for that model.

Pseudo code:

```
def rename_s3(old_key, new_key):
  s3.copy(old_key, new_key)
  s3.delete(old_key)

def rename_multiple(dict_of_keys):
  for old_key, new_key in dict_of_keys:
    rename_s3(old_key, new_key)
```

Can't remember exactly, but the actual code of copying can look like this:

```
from boto3.session import Session

session = Session(aws_access_key_id="X", aws_secret_access_key="Y")
s3 = session.resource('s3')

source_bucket = s3.Bucket("bucket-A")
target_bucket = s3.Bucket("bucket-B") # this can be "bucket-A" if you want to copy it in the same bucket

old_key = "path/to/old/file/my.csv"
new_key = "path/to/new/file/my_new_name.csv"
target_bucket.copy(Key= new_key, CopySource={"Bucket": "bucket-A", "Key": old_key})
```

Solution presented above has advantage of copying files between buckets belonging to different accounts (as long as account-B has read access to account-A).

Note that you can also use accelerated copy using S3.Client.copy, however it does not support copying files between different regions (Note in documentation).

Some nice links:

[Boto3 Docs 1.13.21 documentation(S3.Bucket.copy)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3#S3.Bucket.copy)

[Boto3 Docs 1.13.21 documentation(S3.Client.copy)](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3#S3.Client.copy)

[Example tutorial on copying files](https://medium.com/plusteam/move-and-rename-objects-within-an-s3-bucket-using-boto-3-58b164790b78)